# Problem with importing a module on python

Tags: python, module

I have a problem with module that I can't import in python: it is called `instaloader`.

When I want to import it, it returns this error message :

```
import instaloader as i
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instaloader\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .instaloader import Instaloader
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloader.py", line 2, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Users\Oussama\json.py", line 6, in <module>
    response=re.get("")
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "c:\users\oussama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can import `instaloader` as `import instaloader`. The [documentation](https://instaloader.github.io/as-module.html#instaloader-main-class) for `instaloader` shows that you can make an instance of `instaloader` and use it for your program.

#### Code from Docs

```
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
```

Comment: Then you can use the `L` methods for your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module in Python, you use `import` then the name of the module.
For example,

```
import instaloader
```

to import the module.